# Android video view streaming is slow, takes time to start video

Tags: android, android-videoview

When I try to play a  remote video using video view in android, the video starts playing after 6-7 seconds. On the same internet connection, if I use a browser to play the same video, it starts playing within 2 seconds. I can see that youtube app takes a max of 2 seconds to start any 720p video on android on my internet connection (assuming it is native and would be using some android video player to play video). Is it possible to speed up video view startup time? do I need to create a new thread and play video on it ?

EDIT : added code

```
View myVideoView = new android.widget.VideoView(args.context);
myVideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
myVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
MediaController myMediaController = new android.widget.MediaController(args.context);
myMediaController.setAnchorView(myVideoView);
myVideoView.setMediaController(myMediaController);

myVideoView.setVideoPath(url);
myVideoView.start();
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing?  Show some code.

Comment: You could try prefetching the video file, saving it somewhere and playing it at once when needed.

Comment: Prefetching a huge file can be an issue. We need a streaming module for the web server and a suitable video player that can seek faster.